# error using cspade invalid "timeout" argument

Tags: r

I'm trying out cspade in the arulesSequences package and getting this error and I'm not sure why. I updated all my packages and am using the most current version of R. I even tried an example posted [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/arulesSequences/html/cspade.html)
. This is what happens for me:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(arulesSequences)
data(zaki)
s0 <- cspade(zaki, parameter = list(support = 0,
                                maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1),
              control   = list(verbose = TRUE))
```

> parameter specification:
> support : 0
> maxsize : 1
> maxlen  : 1

> algorithmic control:
> bfstype  : FALSE
> verbose  :  TRUE
> summary  : FALSE
> tidLists : FALSE

> preprocessing ...Error in system(command, flag, f, stdout, stderr, timeout) :
> invalid 'timeout' argument